# What's the technical term for "ternary interpolation"?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, bezier-curve

While researching how to render 2D bezier curves given the control points, I found a simple formula and the resource where I found this marked this iterative process as a *ternary interpolation* and *ternary approximation* .

Using this 2 keywords I can't find basically any hit while searching with my favourite search engine and I'm wondering if this is a jargon or a term that is just made up by the author .

The "philosophy" of this iterative process looks really similar to what happens in the 3D world with a lattice that is subject to the Catmull-Clark subdivision, it also looks similar to what is shown in this [youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mX0NB9IyYpU) .

Altough all this 3 examples are different, they appear to be connected and I'm wondering if there is a better and more generalized name for that *ternary interpolation* that can help me with this researches .

For example the formula for 2D cubic bezier curves, considering my original source, is

$$\mathbf{B}(t)=(1-t)^3\mathbf{P}_0 + 3(t-2t^2+t^3)\mathbf{P}_1 + 3(t^2-t^3)\mathbf{P}_2 + t^3\mathbf{P}_3$$

And the thing I noted is that the coefficient in this case are $1,3,3,1$, and it looks like a tuple used in the video I mentioned .

What's the general case and the wording to use here ?

Comment: [Here's that formula on the Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve#Cubic_B.C3.A9zier_curves).

Comment: @AntonioVargas I already have the formula, apparently I need to fix the wording and identify the general case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bézier curves are connected with Catmull-Clark subdivision surfaces because both are fundamentally "corner cutting" algorithms. If you stay away from so-called "extraordinary points, the C-C algorithm will produce a b-spline surface, which is closely related to Bézier curves and surfaces.

The term " ternary" is non-standard, and probably refers to the degree (3) of the Bézier curve. Bézier curves can have any degree, but degree 3 is by far the most common.

Comment: I'm interested in studying more of this, algorithms in discrete geometry that connect points to curves, where should I go or what should I consider ?

Comment: There's not much for curves. Look up de Casteljau's algorithm, or Chaikin's algorithm, or "blossoming". There are many different kinds of subdivision schemes for surfaces. Examples are Sabin-Doo, Kobbelt, butterfly.

Comment: I have expanded on that too and found the Chaikin algorithm myself before seeing your comment; it looks like it's the algorithm used in that video, I still can't find 3D examples/algorithms on that tho .

Answer (score 1):

I think "ternary" is a mistranslation of "3rd degree". The conventional  terms would be *cubic interpolation* and *cubic approximation*.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary interpolation could be referring to ternary interpolation subdivision scheme commonly used to generate a smooth curve out of a series of points. This scheme will insert two new points in between each two original points, making the resolution of the curve 3 times higher. The resulting curve will also interpolate the original data points.

Comment: How many other schemes exist, how I can expand my studies on the subject ?